# Easiest way to get Class UML from java(android) files or project w/o eclipse. Reverse engineer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uml

How to get Class UML diagram from Android project (android studio) or Java files, w/o using Eclipse?

Maybe there is some guides or tuttorials how to do it?

Comment: No it is not duplicate because i need to do it w/o using eclipse! :)

Comment: OK, then it's off topic, since you're asking for a tool (or a very long piece of code).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to find a tool able to:

1. reverse your code in order to obtain UML models (without diagram)
2. create your diagrams

I do not know any tool doing this in a unique step but some of them can automatically generate class diagram from models.

stackoverflow is not really the best place from tool discussion but let me know if you do not find any.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com) to reverse engineering your Java code to get the UML model. Then drag&drop the classes you want to show in your diagram.